# What is $\varepsilon$ in black body curve formula?

Tags: terminology, thermal-radiation, notation, telescopes

I'm currently trying to see the intensity vs wavelength curve for different temperatures using [this graphing simulator](https://www.spectraplot.com/blackbody). However, apart from the temperature and range parameters, there is an epsilon parameter (circled in red) whose existence I don't understand. How does it affect the curve, and why is it there?
[image: 2]

Also, I'm doing this for a blog explaining why the Hubble is too hot to detect infrared correctly (the Hubble itself emits infrared signals because its too hot), but the JWST can. Would it be correct to correlate the black body radiation with radiation from the body of the telescopes? Can I make the argument that as the black body emits lots of infrared in the Hubble's temperature, and very less in the JWST's temperature, the same is true for the telescopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing it is the [emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity) which is a factor that you multiply by the curve because things are not perfect blackbodies, depending on what the surface is made of.

Comment: thank you! yea apart from the temperature, distance from the sun, heatshield, etc, the JWST is probably even made of low emissivity material to lower its radiation.

Answer (score 1):

Black body radiation is the maximal possible thermal radiation ($\varepsilon = 1$). Real bodies are not perfect BBs, so the most primitive factor taking this into account is $\varepsilon \le 1$. It a factor (multiplier) at the specrtal curve.

Comment: oh thank you very much. That really cleared things up.